# If $G \to G'$ are isomorphic groups, then $|Aut(G)| = |$ all isomophisms $G \to G'|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I'm having trouble proving this.

If $G$ is finite (which is not given) with $|G| = N$, then $Aut(G)$ can be seen as a symmetry group with order $N!$, so there are $N!$ possible isomorphisms $G \to G'$. So intuitively I understand why $|Aut(G)| = |$all isomorphisms $G \to G'|$.

My first thought was, try to find a bijection between $Aut(G)$ and $H = \{$all isomorphism $G \to G'\}$, by using a fixed $f: G \to G'$. But now I'm stuck.

I'm not looking for a proof, but rather some more insight/help with the thought process.

Comment: Intuitively, if $G'$ is isomorphic to $G$, then the two are 'identical twins' and each one can be substituted for the other; this means that the set of isomorphisms $G\mapsto G'$ is exactly the same as the set of isomorphisms $G\mapsto G$.  This can be formalized by composing the maps appropriately, as in carmichael's answer.

Comment: Do note that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ very rarely has order $|G|!$ for finite groups.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $f_1,f_2:G\to G^{\prime}$ are isomorphisms, then $f_2^{-1}\circ f_1$ is an automorphism of $G$.

Comment: So for every $x \in Aut(G)$ there exists an $y \in H$ such that $y^{-1} \circ y: G \to G$. And $x = y^{-1} \circ y \in Aut(G)$, so for every $y \in H$ there exists an $x \in Aut(G)$. ?

Comment: Sorry that last sentence makes no sense. I get the feeling I should try something with a conjugate map?

Comment: Not quite. Fix an isomorphism $f:G\to G^{\prime}$, then the bijection $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\to H$ is given by $\phi\mapsto f\circ\phi$ and $\psi\mapsto f^{-1}\circ \psi$.

Comment: I understand now, I should've used composition. You always end up with $G \to G$ or $G' \to G$. Now I can easily show that it is indeed bijective. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see why you would need both $\phi$ and $\psi$ though, isn't one sufficient?

Comment: $\phi$ is an element of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, $\psi$ is an element of $H$.

Comment: I am still confused by your wording. Do you mean the bijection $Aut(G) \to H$ is given by both $\phi \mapsto f \circ \phi$ AND $\phi \mapsto f^{-1} \circ \phi$, because that makes no sense to me. Or do you mean $Aut(G) \to H$ is given by $\phi \mapsto f \circ \phi$, and $H \to Aut(G)$ is given by both $\phi \mapsto f^{-1} \circ phi$.

Comment: I meant the second statement. One way of exhibiting a bijection is to describe both the map and its inverse.